# Unable to play feed on cloud podcast player (Pocket casts)

Tags: rss-reader, podcasts

The app, https://play.pocketcasts.com, [builtWith](https://builtwith.com/?https%3A%2F%2Fplay.pocketcasts.com), doesn't map the following RSS feed from Amazon's Audible,

http://feeds.audible.com/rss/subs/aa/B002VA9L8E/ae/26000015440d13004d004e022913190d0c4c4202020f/c/aax_22

[image]

So far, their tech support insisted disabling the Chrome app, "Data Saver", which helped for other feeds. Also they asked if hitting play after receiving the message, "The episode could not be played", helps. It does not.

I have a half dozen, fairly light, chrome extensions. Does anyone have insights using other platforms or this one? Are we overlooking something?

Comment: Have you tried with extensions disabled? Another browser?

Comment: not a paid tester, hoping to crowd source their knowledge base/ [community support](http://support.pocketcasts.com/). is there an extension to easily disable all extensions?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-extensions-tempor/lcfdefmogcogicollfebhgjiiakbjdje?hl=en